# Python Plotly - How to overlay grid lines on a contour plot?

Tags: contour, plotly-python

I am using python plotly and am trying to overlay grid lines on a contour plot.  The following code does not generate an error but it also does not show grid lines.  How can I make the grid lines show?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a good way. The grid layer is there (you can see it if you add opacity<1 in your contour) but you cannot put the grid layer above the traces (or at least I didn't find a way reading the doc and the code).

I ended up rebuilding the grid on top:

```
def add_box(lfig, x, y):
    lfig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        opacity=0.5,
        marker_color='white',
        line_width=1,
    ))
    
def compute_horizontal_lines(x_min, x_max, y_data):
    x = np.tile([x_min, x_max, None], len(y_data))
    y = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[a, a, None] for a in y_data]))
    return x, y

def compute_vertical_lines(y_min, y_max, x_data):
    y = np.tile([y_min, y_max, None], len(x_data))
    x = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[a, a, None] for a in x_data]))
    return x, y
                  
hx, hy = compute_horizontal_lines(200, 20000, range(-150, 180, 30))
vrange = [100*i for i in range(3, 9)] + [1000*i for i in range(1, 10)] + [10000+1000*i for i in range(1, 5)]
vx, vy = compute_vertical_lines(-180, 180, vrange)

add_box(fig, hx, hy)
add_box(fig, vx, vy)

fig.show()
```

which give me something like:
[contour plot with a grid on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQL03.png)